# MySQL replication: failover scenario

Tags: mysql, replication, failover

I have the following MySQL instances, along with a replication setup:

**S1** -----> (**M1** <--> **M2**), where:

M1 - M2 is a multi-master replication setup,

S1 - a slave which replicates the writes which are done at Master M1.

Now, I'm trying to enhance the setup with a channel failover mechanism, where S1 would start replicating from M2, should M1 go down. Currently, the only way of doing this that I see is:

(M1 failure detection mechanism on S1 machine), then:

-> S1 gets the latest timestamp of M1's queries from the local relay log file.

-> M2 searches (bash script using mysqlbinlog utility) for the local **binlog file** + **binlog index** which corresponds to S1's latest timestamp

-> S1 can finally do a "STOP SLAVE", "CHANGE MASTER TO master_host=M2... master_log_file=... master_log_pos=...", etc. command to continue replication, but from M2 this time

Is there a better (and less error prone) way of doing this?

Thank you

**EDIT**: Nowadays, this is much easier to achieve thanks to the unique `Xid` binlog query tags commonly used by the publicly accessible MySQL clustering solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a more simplistic way to retrieve the binlog and position needed.

Would it make more sense to just use the current binlog and position as M2 knows it ? You need to check the Slave status on M2.

## Example

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 10.64.51.130
                  Master_User: replicant
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000463
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 453865699
               Relay_Log_File: relay-bin.001226
                Relay_Log_Pos: 453865845
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000463
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: search_cache
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 453865699
              Relay_Log_Space: 453866038
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 106451130
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

For this display, there are five crucial components:

- Master_Log_File (Line 6) : Log File on the Master whose position was last read
- Read_Master_Log_Pos (Line 7) : Last position read on the Slave from the Master
- Relay_Master_Log_File (Line 10) : Log File on the Master whose position was last executed
- Exec_Master_Log_Pos (Line 22) : Last position executed on the Slave from the Master
- Relay_Log_Space (Line 23) : Sum of bytes from all relay logs

## `Relay_Log_Space`

Please note `Relay_Log_Space`. Once this number stops incrementing, every SQL statement imported from the Master has been read. Unfortunately, it is possible that the last relay log may be corrupt or simply incomplete because of a sudden failover.

## `Replication Coordinates`

Please also note that the Replication Coordinates `(Relay_Master_Log_File, Exec_Master_Log_Pos)`. This is the position you are hunting for. However, like `Relay_Log_Space` it may still be incrementing. In fact, those Replication Coordinates should be equal to the other Replication Coordinates `(Master_Log_File,Read_Master_Log_Pos )`. That's when you know everything is caught up. If the pair of Replication Coordinates never meet, then you should rely on `Relay_Log_Space` a little more in terms of when it stops incrementing.

## What about `Seconds_Behind_Master` ?

The reason you cannot use `Seconds_Behind_Master` is simple. Once a Master goes down hard, all it takes just one Replication thread (`Slave_IO_Running` or `Slave_SQL_Running`) to become `No` and `Seconds_Behind_Master` turns `NULL`.